# How to restrict/hide OOTB document libraries creation

Tags: 2010, document-library, content-type, document-template

Is there a way to restrict the out of the box document libraries like "Document Library" "Picture Library" etc and just have custom document libraries being shown in the pop-up below?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your requirement to hide the action or prevent users from creating new lists in the SharePoint site? You could prevent users from creating lists by making them a contributer or create a custom permission level.

You can use the SPRoleDefinition class to programmatically create a permission level. Take a look at

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sproledefinition.aspx
```

Edit: There is another option.  That is to unregister the document library list template from the site. You can do that by disabling the feature:

```
 Disable-SPFeature 00BFEA71-E717-4E80-AA17-D0C71B360101 -Url http://sharepoint/example
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution for SP2013+ is to override "Noteworthy" section on the "Add an app" page.

The below script is mostly based on the following post [Hiding the out-of-the-box Document Library in SharePoint 2013](https://spmatt.wordpress.com/2014/05/21/hiding-the-out-of-the-box-document-library-in-sharepoint-2013/).
Basically, a JSLink overrides Apps Noteworthy section:

```
var MyModule = MyModule || {};
MyModule.AppCatalog = MyModule.AppCatalog || {};
MyModule.AppCatalog.NoteWorthyOverrider = function (){

    var alterStorefront = function () {
        if (SP.Storefront != undefined) {
            var listedApps = SP.Storefront.StorefrontApp.get_currentView();
            if (listedApps == undefined || listedApps.$2i_3 == null || listedApps.$L_3 == null) { setTimeout(alterStorefront, 300); return; }

            listedApps.$2i_3.length = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < listedApps.$L_3.length; i++) {
                if (listedApps.$L_3[i].$2Q_0.Title === "Document Library") {
                    listedApps.$L_3.splice(i, 1);
                }
                if (listedApps.$L_3[i].$2Q_0.Title.indexOf("Insite") > -1 || listedApps.$L_3[i].$2Q_0.Title === "My Custom Library Template") {
                    listedApps.$2i_3.push(listedApps.$L_3[i]);
                }
            }

            SP.Storefront.StorefrontApp.get_currentView().updateUI();
        }
    };

    return {
        AlterStorefront : alterStorefront
    }
}(); 

if (window.location.href.indexOf("_layouts/15/addanapp.aspx") > 0 || window.location.href.indexOf("_layouts/addanapp.aspx") > 0){
    SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.Storefront", MyModule.AppCatalog.NoteWorthyOverrider.AlterStorefront);
}
```

**Notes:**

- This solution will not "hide" ootb templates, users can still find them using Search box.
- Applies to SP2013+